# Regex for event log 4624 logon type and account name

Tags: regex

I need some help with regex which I am still trying to teach myself. I have beaten my head on this for hours. I am trying to filter logon events in my event log via a syslog server. I would like to only capture actual user logons not all the other stuff coming through.

Computer and user accounts are on the line that says "ACCOUNT NAME:". The computer accounts contain a $ appended to the end of their name and I need to filter those out while accepting the ones without the $ on the end.

The log comes through like this:

> Logon Type:         3
>
> Impersonation Level:      Impersonation
>
> New Logon:
>     Security ID:      S-1-5-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Account Name:      COMPUTERNAME$
>
> Account Domain:(random whitespace)      DomainName
>
> Logon ID:      0xXXXXXXXXX
>
> Logon GUID:      {XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
>
> Process Information:
>     Process ID:      0x0
>     Process Name:      -
>
> Network Information:
>     Workstation Name:   -
>
> Source Network Address:   192.168.0.x
>
> Source Port:      000000

Any regex pro that can assist? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear. If you already handled "Logon Type" successfully and it's not relevant to your question - remove it!
Try to be very explicit in regards to input, requested output and what's the output that you're getting with the current regex you're using. Also, try to format your question (spend a few minutes to check which button is doing what to your text, format code or input/output so it's easy to distinct it from the text of the question). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a regex pro, but I can help you with this specific problem. Use a `look ahead` to filter the dollar sign off, like this:

```
(?!.*\$)
```

This is called a `negative look ahead` '`(?!`' and it looks for any char any number of times `'.*'` UNTIL there's a '`$`' sign. If a dollar sign is found, no match.

Note that the dollar sign is escaped in the regex.

**Edit**:

To match account name and not dollar sign, it becomes (assuming account names doesn't contain Spaces):

```
(?!.*\$)Account Name:\s*(\w+)
```

Now grap the account in `Group 1.`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`Account Name:\s*([^\s\$]+[^\s\$]$)`

https://regex101.com/r/0W8xVg/3